# Passing value from textbox to extension in a chrome_extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am a new chrome extension person. I am working on building an extension that will do one of two things:

1. take a selection in the current tab (whatever the user has highlighted) and copy it into a "source" text field in popup.hmtl so that the user can then select a language and translate it (using google translate).
2. IF the currently active tab has a given ID for a text field, copy the contents of THAT field to the "source" text field in popup.html (so the user can then translate, etc.)

I can make #1 work just fine, but when I try to build #2 into the code, it always returns null, even though I know for a fact that this ID is present.

I am not sure what is wrong, and I am really not sure how to make this work. The working code is below (really only three files - manifest.json, popup.html, and popup_script.js)

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version" : 2,
"name" : "CSOne Translation Prototype",
"description" : "Extension to translate CSOne comments and email to 
customer",
"version" : "1.0",
"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "storage", "<all_urls>"],
"browser_action" : {
"default_title" : "Clock",
"default_icon" : "icon.png",
"default_popup" : "popup.html"
},

"icons" : {
"16": "icon16.png",
"48" : "icon48.png",
"128" : "icon128.png"
}
```

}

popup_script.js (API Key removed for security)

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, 

function selectTxt(selection) {
console.log(selection[0]);
document.getElementById("txtSource").value = selection[0];
});


$("#btnTranslate").click(function () {
var url = "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2? 
key=<GOOGLEAPIKEY>;
        url += "&source=" + $("#ddlSource").val();
        url += "&target=" + $("#ddlTarget").val();
        url += "&q=" + escape($("#txtSource").val());
        $.get(url, function (data, status) {
            $("#txtTarget").val(data.data.translations[0].translatedText);
        });
    });
```

And popup.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Source Language
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="ddlSource">
                <option value="ZH">Chinese (Mandarin)</option>
                <option value="CS">Czech</option>
                <option value="DA">Danish</option>
                <option value="NL">Dutch</option>
                <option value="EN" selected = "selected">English</option>
                <option value="ET">Estonian</option>
                <option value="FR">French</option>
                <option value="KA">Georgian</option>
                <option value="DE">German</option>
                <option value="HI">Hindi</option>
                <option value="HU">Hungarian</option>
                <option value="LA">Latin</option>
                <option value="LV">Latvian</option>
                <option value="LT">Lithuanian</option>
                <option value="SR">Serbian</option>
                <option value="CY">Welsh</option>
                <option value="XH">Xhosa</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            Target Language
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="ddlTarget">
                <option value="ZH">Chinese (Mandarin)</option>
                <option value="CS">Czech</option>
                <option value="DA">Danish</option>
                <option value="NL">Dutch</option>
                <option value="EN">English</option>
                <option value="ET">Estonian</option>
                <option value="FR" selected = "selected">French</option>
                <option value="KA">Georgian</option>
                <option value="DE">German</option>
                <option value="HI">Hindi</option>
                <option value="HU">Hungarian</option>
                <option value="LA">Latin</option>
                <option value="LV">Latvian</option>
                <option value="LT">Lithuanian</option>
                <option value="SR">Serbian</option>
                <option value="CY">Welsh</option>
                <option value="XH">Xhosa</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" id="btnTranslate" value="Translate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea id="txtSource" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea id="txtTarget" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, I know the source page has a text box that has a given ID in it (See HTML snippet below):

snippet from the page I want to source from

```
<textarea id="j_id0:j_id443:quickEdit:frmQuickEdit:NoteText" 
name="j_id0:j_id443:quickEdit:frmQuickEdit:NoteText" class="con-MonoSpace 
qedit-NoteArea" title="Note" style="height: 157.406px;"></textarea>
```

So, I tried to change my popup_script.js to include this sort of code:

'update' popup_script.js (note, in the document.getElementById sections below, I had to change the actual ID to  in order to get the formatting right in this post - in the actual code, it is hard coded as "j_id0:j_id443:quickEdit:frmQuickEdit:NoteText"

```
var csoneCommentID = document.getElementById("<IDABOVE>").value;
function selectTxt(selection) {
console.log(selection[0]);
document.getElementById("txtSource").value = selection[0];

if (csoneCommentID == "null")
{
    alert("CSOne Note Field is empty, copying selection for translation");
    document.getElementById("txtSource").value = selection[0];
}
else if
(document.getElementById("<IDABOVE>").value != "null")
    {
    alert("CSOne Note field contains text - copying for translation");
    document.getElementById("txtSource").value =
document.getElementById("<IDABOVE>").value;
    }

  });
```

Now, if I try to use the 'updated' popup_script.js, I always get an error of:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at the first line:

Uncaught TypeError here:

```
var csoneCommentID = document.getElementById("<IDABOVE>").value;
```

So... I am really not sure how to get the value that exists in that text area to be sent to the extension. To be clear, I am hoping I am can send this data even before it is submitted in the form in the 'starting' page (the page the user would be on before clicking the extension action button). Also, when the user is on this starting page, the selection part (option 1 at the top of this post) does not work either, but that option DOES work if they are on any other page (I can select text here on stackoverflow, for example, and click the extension and it gets pasted into the source translation field in the extension - IF i use the unmodified popup_script.js).

Any help would be appreciated, and I am new to this, so please be kind... :)

Thank you so much!

EDIT -

Following the suggestions below, I added a content.js script, which produces similar failures, which I simply don't understand why:

content.js

```
var extensionID = "efkednjacmmjkkdndkbkmglmenkepgkg";
var csoneElementID = "j_id0:j_id443:quickEdit:frmQuickEdit:NoteText";
var greeting = "Starting Content Script";
var message = "Content Script running";
function responseCallback(responseObject){
console.log("Message '" + responseObject.message + "' from Sender '" + 
responseObject.sender + "'");
}
console.log(greeting);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(dcle){
var elementID = document.getElementById(csoneElementID);
elementID.addEventListener("select",function(ce){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionID,message,responseCallback);
    });
});
```

This produces a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at HTMLDocument. (content.js:11)"

Line 11 is 'elementID.addEventListener("select",function(ce)'

I thought the idea behind the content script was to allow it to see the underlying/calling html page? So, why is it returning a null? I can't figure out what I am missing (I've tried different types of DOM events there too, to no avail)... I feel like the answer is right in front of my face...

ANOTHER EDIT -

In looking through the Chrome developer tools for the source page (the one with the crazy long text area ID I am looking to copy contents FROM), I see the part of my content.js 'console.log(greeting)' IS firing (I see console messages there that say "Starting Content Script", and that message goes away if I turn off my extension and reload - so I know it isn't from some other extension/etc.) - So, I know the content.js page IS running on that page, but it just doesn't seem to send my popup_script.js any actual content. So I added 'console.log("csoneElementID = '" + csoneElementID + "'");' after the 'var elementID' section to log what it was gathering, and it returns "csoneElementID = '' "... I can't figure this out and I am feeling like I am missing the forest for the trees...

Thanks

Comment: The popup is a totally separate page, not related to the web page. It's a small window that runs chrome-extension://id/popup.html. It can't access web page DOM directly. Only a content script can do it.

Comment: Ok - I think I understand that. Maybe a better way to ask my question is, "Is what I am trying to do at all possible? Is it possible to have the extension grab the contents of that portion of the form and put it into the popup.html?"

Comment: Sorry, I mis read your reply... So, a content script can do it, but I don't know how to do that? Do I simply move that "if" statement into a content script and call that from the manifest file?

Comment: Uhm, I thought you'd go read the documentation about content scripts or look at some demo extensions... You're already running a content script code in chrome.tabs.executeScript.

Comment: :) I am reading it, but it doesn't make sense or work for me... That is why i am confused... in the script that does work, I don't have a content script, only the popup_script I listed. I am trying to experiment with a content script right now to see if it clicks... But even the 'demo' script in the google documentation doesn't do anything for me... Hmmm...  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though... now that I know I have to use a content script, I just have to figure out why it isn't working for me...

Comment: Note, the `code` or `file` that you run with tabs.executeScript is a content script too. The important distinction here is that it runs in the web page.